# Serial.begin(speed, config) not compiling for Leonardo Board

Tags: arduino

I would like to configure my serial communication to have no parity, 1 start- and 2 stop-bits. The [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin) for `Serial.begin(speed, config)` states:

> (...) An optional second argument configures the data, parity, and stop bits. The default is 8 data bits, no parity, one stop bit.

The documentation also lists the possible configuration-values. According to my (limited) understanding, I need SERIAL_7N2 or SERIAL_8N2 to meet my requirements. (I'm not sure how the data-bits relate to the the 1-start-bit that I need.)

However, I can't even compile because I have no idea how to supply that configuration value to the begin method. (I don't have much Arduino/C++ experience).

In my code, I've tried the following two variants:

```
Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2);
Serial.begin(9600, "SERIAL_8N2");
```

Am I missing something?

Additional information:

`Serial.begin(speed, config)` has been introduced with the latest [Arduino 1.0.2 IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes) version.

The code defining/implementing the begin methods can be found:

- [HardwareSerial.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h)
- [HardwareSerial.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp)

---

Edit:

According to the replies from PeterJ and borges, the following variant is correct.

```
Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2);
```

However, it's still not working.

I found that the compile error doesn't occur if I change the configured board from my Arduino Leonardo to [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno).

Therefore, it could be a bug occurring only with a subset of boards ... or maybe it's not supported?!

---

Edit 2:

It's now solved :) The answer of borges pointed me to the right solution!

Comment: `Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2)` should be enough. Are you using the IDE version `1.0.2`?

Comment: Thanks, but yes I'm definitely using 1.0.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment: (edit: and now is in the title)

> I don't get the compile error if I change the board from my "Arduino Leonardo" to "Arduino Uno".

The Arduino Leonardo has some peculiarities regarding serial communication:

1. Leonardo has a microcontroller ([ATmega32U4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega32u4.aspx)) that has native USB communication. To maintain compatibility as the entire ecosystem already established, the Leonardo virtualizes a serial communication over USB. You have access to this communication using `Serial` in the code. Physically you have access to that communication via the USB plug.
2. To use the "real" serial communication (AKA serial TTL), you need to use pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). In the code you would use `Serial1` (notice the number 1!).

An example:

```
void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2);
    Serial1.println("Hello?");
}

void loop() {
}
```

For more information (recommended):

- [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo)
- [Guide to the Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardo)

Answer (score 1):

The first method should be OK, so you have a compiler configuration or include problem. Make sure you have the following include at the top of your file:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
```

Also while SERIAL_8N2 is valid it's an odd setting rarely used. You'll most likely want SERIAL_8N1.

Comment: Thanks, but the include did not help. However ... I just found out that I don't get the compile error if I change the board from my "Arduino Leonardo" to "Arduino Uno".

Comment: ... and the motor-controller I want to communicate with needs according to it's specs "Serial mode at 9600 bps, 1 start bit, 2 stop bits, no parity" ... wouldn't that be SERIAL_8N2?

Comment: Good it's sorted out. Yes SERIAL_8N2 is correct for that configuration, but it remains a fairly unusual one so in the future if you're interfacing with anything unknown SERIAL_8N1 is the best one to start with.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will keep that in mind :) But why can't I use the method with my Arduino Leonardo Board? Is it a bug? Should I file an issue? Or is it just not supported?

Comment: I've never used that particular board but the AVR used does have a hardware UART so I guess it's something they haven't implemented yet so would be worth filing an issue on. Meanwhile you might be able to try SoftwareSerial to see if that's supported.